# Is there a way to comment out markup in an .ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, markup, comments

Is there a way to comment out markup in an `.ASPX` page so that it isn't delivered to the client? I have tried the standard comments `<!-- -->` but this just gets delivered as a comment and doesn't prevent the control from rendering.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

```
<%--
            Commented out HTML/CODE/Markup.  Anything with
            this block will not be parsed/handled by ASP.NET.

            <asp:Calendar runat="server"></asp:Calendar> 

            <%# Eval(“SomeProperty”) %>     
--%>
```

[Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/09/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx)

Answer (score 77):

Bonus answer: The keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio for commenting out anything is **Ctrl-KC** . This works in a number of places, including C#, VB, Javascript, and aspx pages; it also works for SQL in SQL Management Studio.

You can either select the text to be commented out, or you can position your text inside a chunk to be commented out; for example, put your cursor inside the opening tag of a GridView, press Ctrl-KC, and the whole thing is commented out.

Answer (score 31):

FYI | <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> is the comment shortcut in Visual Studio. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> uncomments.

Answer (score 28):

```
<%-- not rendered to browser --%>
```

Answer (score 13):

I believe you're looking for:

```
<%-- your markup here --%>
```

That is a serverside comment and will not be delivered to the client ... but it's not optional.  If you need this to be programmable, then you'll want [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/121397/2415524) :-)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there are special server side comments:

```
<%-- Text not sent to client  --%>
```

Answer (score 9):

While this works:

```
<%-- <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ht_tv1.Default" %> --%>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Blank._Default" %>
```

This won't.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" <%--Inherits="ht_tv1.Default"--%> Inherits="Blank._Default" %>
```

So you can't comment out part of something which is what I want to do 99.9995% of the time.

Answer (score 5):

Another way assuming it's not server side code you want to comment out is...

```
<asp:panel runat="server" visible="false">
    html here
</asp:panel>
```

Comment: I did delete this answer as its not strictly 'commenting out'.  However, Joel's answer refers to mine so for the time being I've undeleted it.

Comment: asp:PlaceHolder does the same but is designed to not generate any additional HTML.