# what does this aspx markup sequence mean

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

what does

<%-- one or more lines of html markup or javascript --%>

mean on an aspx page.  visual studio 2010 highlights in a way as to suggest its a comment or that it has been conditionalized out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a comment, I would call it server side comment as it's contents won't be delivered to client (browser) as opposed to normal html comments `<!-- comments -->` , take a look at [Is there a way to comment out markup in an .ASPX page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121382/is-there-a-way-to-comment-out-markup-in-an-aspx-page) .

Answer (score 0):

Its a comment, that text wont be parsed/proccessed by asp.net and wont be delivered to the browser